# Getting percent value and add to table

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to create a percentage from free disk space and add it to each disk, so we can get a true reading of what disks can be reduced and disk usage.

The script I have is:

```
$Computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like 'My-VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object
foreach ($computer in $Computers) 
{
 gwmi Win32_volume -Computer $Computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3' `
  | select PsComputerName, DriveLetter, Label,
           @{n='Capacity';e={[int]($_.capacity/1GB)}}, 
           @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}} | Format-Table -Groupby PsComputerName |`
            Out-File c:\temp\disk_label.txt -Append
          }
```

I can get percentage using the following, however I have no idea how to get the freedisk value and capacity value, which I can then divide and multiply by 100 to get percentage disk free

```
$free = 20
$capacity = 50

$Freedisk = (($free / $capacity) * 100)

Value = $freedisk
```

Please could you let me know where I'm going wrong...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question, since you seem to already have all the info.  Did you write the code above or copy it from somewhere (in other words, do you understand it all).

You can add `PercentFree` to your output easily by adapting this code below.  In all cases where there is a complicated pipeline, I unroll it into variables and debug each part in the ISE/VSCode.

```
$computer = '127.0.0.1'
$vol = gwmi Win32_volume -Computer $Computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3'
$vol

$info = $vol | select PsComputerName, DriveLetter, Label,
           @{n='Capacity';e={[int]($_.capacity/1GB)}}, 
           @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
           @{n='PercentFree';e={[int](($_.FreeSpace) / ($_.capacity) * 100.0)}}

$info
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat, I didn't create the script I did manipulate it for what I needed, however I I was making the mistake of putting another `[int]` before `($_.Capacity)` which was returning blank Percentfree value. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: No problem @NorrinRad.  In general, it's always best to keep the full data type (decimal/float) through all calculations, or  you my lose data, or round something to zero and perhaps even cause a divide by zero.  Glad you're unblocked now.